# Azure Pipeline - Get associated git TAG?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, git-tag

On my pipeline, I can retrieve the build number using the variable `RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.MyPipeline_BUILDID`. But I was wondering, how can I get the TAG associated with the build.

It is visible within the pipeline like:

[image]

is there a way to capture it in a variable within the yml so I properly concatenate it like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) `SourceBranch`:

> The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for.
> When your pipeline is triggered by a tag: `refs/tags/your-tag-name`

So, in the release the variable will be `RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.MyPipeline_SOURCEBRANCH`.

Comment: is there a way to remove the "refs/tags/" and get only the tag name?

Comment: I managed using `_SOURCEBRANCHNAME`